# Pass through authorization between web sites

Tags: authorization, identityserver4

We have several sites (sub-1.mycompany.com, sub-2.mycompany.com, sub-n.mycompany.com) that are authenticated through the same identity server. Is it possible to pass through the authorization tokens with or in links (querystrings or so) from one web site to another web site (no Web API). So that an authorized user can use his login for all the sites without a relogin?[image]

Thanks a lot

Uwe

Comment: why do you need to send token? if you have openID setup on all of them, once user is logged in in 1 app, they will be logged in in all apps - web apps uses same identity

Comment: You have to make your applications try to "silently log in" the user. If you're using `oidc-client-js` you can try to `UserManager.signinSilent()` when loading your app, to see if you can automatically log-in the user.

Comment: **Silent Login** sounds good. I will try it out

Answer (score 0):

As Nahidf mentions in a comment:

> why do you need to send token? if you have openID setup on all of them, once user is logged in in 1 app, they will be logged in in all apps - web apps uses same identity

What I need are the [Single Sign-On](https://auth0.com/docs/sso) capabilities of OpenId Connect. The IdentityServer is an certified implementation of OpenID Connect.